# How to edit file in chef cookbook after it's creation with bash

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm writing some chef recipe for app deployment.
I'm extracting the code and then editing it. It looks something like:

```
bash 'admin-init' do
    user "root"
    code <<-EOH
        <here I extract the code>
    EOH
end

execute 'configure' do
  file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new(node["code_dir"] + "websaas/settings.py")
  file.search_file_replace("'HOST': '*'", "'HOST': '" + node["db_host"] + "'")
  file.write_file
end
```

My problem is that during compilation, settings.py is not there yet, so I get:

```
ArgumentError
-------------
File doesn't exist
```

during chef compilation.
How can I solve it?

Thanks, Arshavski Alexander

Comment: This is a particularly hard problem with Chef, in my experience. You want your configuration files managed under source control along side the project code, but you want to have Chef manage the hardware & secrets configurations within. Solutions I've tried/seen that I've not been happy with: move the configuration files completely to your Chef repo, split the configuration options into two files - one in Chef and one in your source code, build an option overriding mechanism so the options in the Chef config file take precedence. +1, hopefully someone else has better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ruby_block` resource, not an `execute` resource.  Your execute resource doesn't even define a command, and thus does effectively nothing.

```
ruby_block 'configure' do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new(node["code_dir"] + "websaas/settings.py")
    file.search_file_replace("'HOST': '*'", "'HOST': '" + node["db_host"] + "'")
    file.write_file
  end
end
```